# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when calling a function

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am wanting to add a callback to some code.

Here is the code before hand:

```
var htmlParent2 = $('#testnohtml');
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2);
$('#text', htmlParent2).html("test text");  

function setHtml(url, parent)
{
    $.get( url, function( data ) {
      parent.html( data );
    });
}
```

Here is what I have written:

```
var htmlParent2 = $('#testnohtml');
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2, function(result))
{
  $('#text', htmlParent2).html("test text");    
}

function setHtml(url, parent, callback)
{
    $.get( url, function( data ) {
      parent.html( data );
    });
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

At this line of code:

```
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2, function(result))
```

Can someone please help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Yeah, function(result) is missing {}

Comment: Don't forget to call `callback()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the syntax error, just passing a callback is not enough, you also need to invoke it

```
var htmlParent2 = $('#testnohtml');
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2, function (result) { //fix the syntax issue here
    $('#text', htmlParent2).html("test text");
})

function setHtml(url, parent, callback) {
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        parent.html(data);
        callback(); //you need to call the callback here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2, function(result)
{
  $('#text', htmlParent2).html("test text");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(` will come after `}` brackets.

```
setHtml("/objects/data.html", htmlParent2, function(result)
{
  $('#text', htmlParent2).html("test text");    
});
```